# MYSQL Query select date ranges which are stored in unix timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to pull a section of data from a table with dates stored as unix timestamps. The trouble I'm having in particular is the WHERE line. I'd like get all rows with the current year and month.

```
SELECT COUNT(rebuild_quote) AS total, resources.name, reservations.machid,
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date) + INTERVAL 4 DAY) AS year,
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date) + INTERVAL 4 DAY) AS month,
SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won,
SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Lost' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lost,
SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Lost' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / (SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN rebuild_quote = 'Lost' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 AS conversion
FROM reservations
LEFT JOIN resources
        ON reservations.machid = resources.machid

**WHERE YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) AND MONTH(start_date) = MONTH(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))**
GROUP BY
      YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date) + INTERVAL 3 DAY), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date) + INTERVAL 3 DAY), machid
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want data of only `current month` or for all `(year,month)` pair?

Comment: Hi, managed to figure it out thanks though. WHERE start_date > 1433116800 AND start_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())

Comment: 1433116800 is the unix_timestamp of Jan 01 2015. do you want Unix_Timestamp of Jan 01 2015 OR Jan 01 2016?